# What is the GPU scheduling method used in DirectX?

Tags: directx, gpu, scheduling

I am curious that what is the GPU scheduling method used in DirectX ?

It's hard for me to get a full picture of DirectX GPU scheduling method by reading this MSDN section

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/video-memory-management-and-gpu-scheduling

---

This paper classified a list of GPU scheduling methods. **Can DirectX's method be identified by this table?**

https://pure.qub.ac.uk/portal/files/130042880/acm_surveys_GPU_2017.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, neither DirectX nor Windows kernel does GPU scheduling. Windows just throws tasks submitted by running software to the GPU, and closely monitors how much time do they take to complete. If it’s more than 2 seconds, Windows detects GPU timeout. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/timeout-detection-and-recovery) for what happens next.

IMO the approach works good enough for desktops. Vast majority of users only run single GPU-demanding application at any given time, so they don’t care about the “scheduler” being a simple FIFO queue.

However, if you’re offering cloud-based GPGPUs like the article you’ve linked, or cloud-based gaming platform [like GameFly](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6331-yuval-sarna-multiple-workloads-gpu.pdf) (now part of EA) you likely want something better. nVidia definitely has true GPU scheduler in their [GRID vGPUs](https://images.nvidia.com/content/grid/pdf/GRID-vGPU-User-Guide.pdf) drivers and/or hardware. I have no idea how it functions, never dealt with that technology.